# Name change of the Jewish site: Mi Yodeya

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

The name Mi Yodeya for the Jewish site concerns me from a usability standpoint, where finding this resource, if one isn't familiar with Hebrew, might only be discovered out of sheer luck. Other religious forums are simply called Christianity, Islam, Buddhism and Hinduism, and are therefore easy to find for knowledge seekers. My question is if the name can be possibly be changed simply to Judaism, or put to a vote, so that anyone who has minimal or no knowledge of Judaism can find it much easier. Seeking opinions on this.

Comment: You're looking for the [Mi Yodeya Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: was now asked on Mi Yodeya Meta https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4461/11501

Answer (score 6):

[judaism.stackexchange.com](https://judaism.stackexchange.com) works. Judaism is an *early* site, and many of them have unique names - Seasoned Advice (aka [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com)) and Arqade aka [Gaming](https://gaming.stackexchange.com).  Note, also, that the "audience" blurb, i.e. the short description you see in the list of sites, is "Q&A for those who base their lives on *Jewish* law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more".

Interestingly - [SE blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/?s=judaism) refers to it as "Jewish Life and Learning".  The site had that name during beta, and (re)gained the name Mi Yodeya upon graduation.  (The SE 1.0 site was named Mi Yodeya.)

Its also, in my experience a far more "technical" site than many other religion sites - so *some* minimal knowledge is useful, if nothing else, to know *Purim Torah* aren't serious ;)

Comment: The SE 1.0 site was named Mi Yodeya, the SE 2.0 beta site was named "Jewish Life & Learning", and upon graduation its original name was restored.  That's why you see references to JL&L.

Comment: ah, this was historical context I lacked, for mildly obvious reasons ;p

Comment: Also, the "audience" blurb, i.e. the short description you see in the list of sites, is "Q&A for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more".  So any confusion about Mi Yodeya is limited to cases where you see the name but neither the URL nor the audience blurb.